# apache-flink operation with the help of docker on raspberry pi [apache-flink]

Tags: java, docker, raspberry-pi, apache-flink, raspbian

this is how the docker-compose structure:

```
version: "3"
services:
  jobmanager:
    image: ${FLINK_DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME:-flink}
    expose:
      - "6123"
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    command: jobmanager
    environment:
      - JOB_MANAGER_RPC_ADDRESS=jobmanager

  taskmanager:
    image: ${FLINK_DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME:-flink}
    expose:
      - "6121"
      - "6122"
      - "9000"
    depends_on:
      - jobmanager
    command: taskmanager
    links:
      - "jobmanager:jobmanager"
    environment:
      - JOB_MANAGER_RPC_ADDRESS=jobmanager
```

I'm getting an error when I do docker-compose up on raspberry

```
taskmanager_1  | Invalid maximum direct memory size: -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=8388607T
taskmanager_1  | The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.
taskmanager_1  | Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
taskmanager_1  | Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

There is a memory error. It works just fine when I run the job_manager. Does Task_manager use more space? Or did I do something wrong? What is the minimum hardware required for Task_manager? Will Flink not work on raspberry? How is it determined? How can I solve this.
 Thank you

Comment: What does `8388607T` means? 8388607 terrabyte? I guess that might be too much for a raspberry pi ;-)

Comment: actually I don't know what exactly it was :) and I didn't find what it meant. My goal is to run on raspberry.